# Как включить конвертацию .md в .html у Jekyll?

Tags: html, github, cms, markdown, jekyll

У джекиля должна быть конвертация маркдауна в хтмл, но я не могу понять как ее включить?

Comment: Все конвертированные из `markdown` в `html` файлы находятся в `_site`

Comment: При чистой установке нужен конвертер, а где его взять я не знаю.

Comment: Он устанавливается вместе с самим Jekyll.

Comment: С флагом --blank - нет

Comment: @brachkoff [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)  `markdown_ext:        "markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md"` эта опция идет по дифолту

Comment: У `gem install` нет флага `--blank`. У вас уже установлен конвертер, вопрос лишь во включении.

Comment: Речь идёт о `jekyll new` с флагом `--blank`